# Day Trading introductory books

Tags: markets, books, recommendation, day-trading

I realize that day trading is considered to be highly risky, but the subject fascinates me and I would like to learn more about it as well as read about past experiences, both good and bad.

Do you recommend any day trading related books? I'm not so much looking for a purely mathematical approach (although that'd also be fine). Rather, I'd like to read about day traders' experiences and how they look at the markets and their volatilities of today (it should thus be fairly recent).

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is the same as my answer for Forex Trading, with appropriate changes:

[Day Trading For Dummies](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047094272X), no offense. The "For Dummies" series is well known for its expertise in every field one can imagine.

That said, what prompts you to want to get into this? The average person is very likely to lose money as the long time experts walk away winners. Do you have an urge to day trade? I sure don't.

While I offer the book as a guide, the real answer is "you shouldn't."

Comment: Do you not consider it a rather significant issue that this book was published in October 29, 2007?

Comment: June 7, 2011 - Thanks for pointing that out. Original link was bad, corrected above.

Comment: "The average person is very likely to lose money".  IMHO, the average person doesn't partake so those of us, like me, who are interested and very new, what would you recommend?  I work for myself, small company, want to diddle with things at night after we put the kids to bed and maybe on the weekends.  I am willing to lose maybe $5K to start.  Call it learning money.  Forex.com seems like a likely candidate with their starter account using simulated funds.  Is FX a good way to start or is there another suggestion(s)?